# Website href links not working, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contact Information</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<h3><a href="directions.html" target="_self">See our Directions!</a></h3>

<p>We open at <time>12:00</time> Monday to Thursday.</p>

<hr/>

<address>Email us at<br/>
cscreamery@gmail.com<br/>
or call us at<br/>
(719)-555-0987</address>

<a href="directions.html">Directions</a>
<a href="Home.html">Home</a>
<a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>

<button type="button">C's Creamery</button>

</html>
```

I have been trying to figure out why my href links are not working no matter what i do. The pages i am trying to connect them to are named like in the code so i am highly confused.

Comment: Are they in the same directory?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @JackBashford they are all in the same folder

Comment: @Barmar can you explain what you mean

Comment: Right-click on the webpage output, and select `Inspect Page`. From there look at the Console tab, and see if there are any errors (red lines). If there are any, what are they?

Comment: What you have now should be working fine, unless you have spelling mistakes in the file names. Try checking file names again to see if they are correct.

Comment: @JackBashford it says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND_" for logo.png But, that image is still showing

Comment: @CiannaD. Does that error happen when you click on a link?

Comment: Is your real HTML different from what you posted? There's no `logo.png` in the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a body tag and then closing tags .. browsers will behave badly ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contact Information</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>

<h3><a href="directions.html" target="_self">See our Directions!</a></h3>

<p>We open at <time>12:00</time> Monday to Thursday.</p>

<hr/>

<address>Email us at<br/>
cscreamery@gmail.com<br/>
or call us at<br/>
(719)-555-0987</address>

<a href="directions.html">Directions</a>
<a href="Home.html">Home</a>
<a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>

<button type="button">C's Creamery</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me where they would go?

Comment: at the bottom and after </head> like in the example above :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check like Home.html and other Html page that you are using for href are located at same folder where your main Html page is located.

I have created a sample.html page from above code and replaced Home.html page with my page
it is working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contact Information</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<h3><a href="relation.html" target="_self">See our Directions!</a></h3>

<p>We open at <time>12:00</time> Monday to Thursday.</p>

<hr/>

<address>Email us at<br/>
cscreamery@gmail.com<br/>
or call us at<br/>
(719)-555-0987</address>

<a href="relation.html">Directions</a>
<a href="role.html">Home</a>
<a href="model.html">Menu</a>

<button type="button">C's Creamery</button>
</html>
```

I have used chrome for it.I have put all the Html page like this webapp/app/view/sample.html and others also are available at view/

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
<body>

<a href="mailto:cscreamery@gmail.com"></i>Email us at
cscreamery@gmail.com</a>
or
<a href="tel:(719)-555-0987"></i>call us at
(719)-555-0987</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you solved it, not just post code. And this code doesn't seem related to the question at all, there are no links in the `href` attributes.